# 401 error while using HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory

Tags: java, spring, rest, httpclient, http-status-code-401

Am getting 401 Unauthorized error for few of the URLs when using HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory, however it works fine when using Simpleclienthttprequestfactory.

The reason why i want to use HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory is for reading the response body of 422 error.

Any thoughts on resolving any one of the below issue ?
1. How to eliminate 401 error while using HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory ? OR
2. How to read the responseBody of 422 error while using Simpleclienthttprequestfactory ? (AFAIK the fix for this is using HttpComponents but it is causing other issues ...)

Answer (score 0):

HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(HttpClients.createSystem());

Adding HttpClients.createSystem() resolved the issue

Answer (score -1):

- When us use curl on the URL you are calling from your HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory are you also getting a 401?
  Since code 401 is unauthorized, you should get a 401 from curl as well.

  - Do you need to set a user/password into the request to have proper credentials?
    Were credentials used by the request sent from Simpleclienthttpsrequestfactor?

You could also try to capture network traffic when making the two requests (from Simple vs. HTTPComponents client) to visualize what EXACTLY is different about the two requests -- because if they are the same, then both should result in a 401 error.

Comment: There were no credentials sent in the request from Simpleclienthttpsrequestfactory, I had not done anything with respect to authentication/authorization from my code... Also, can you share a link to educate on how to capture the traffic ?

Comment: I use wireshark: https://www.wireshark.org/ but there are tools which just focus on HTTP traffic that might be easier to use.  Assuming you do download and install wireshark: try these steps: https://confluence.atlassian.com/kb/how-to-capture-http-traffic-using-wireshark-or-fiddler-779164332.html  (I read them and they appear reasonable) -- except don't follow step 9 since you aren't filing a support ticket.  You can also try fiddler as it's a less general purpose tool than Wireshare, so is easier for developers to use as it's more tailored to web developer needs.